# DLL working in one application but not another -- environmental differences?

Tags: plugins, dll, com, driver

Speaking broadly...

I have a COM DLL that is loaded at run-time. That DLL loads another DLL from an absolute path specified in the registry. When I load the COM DLL in a stand-alone test executable, the second DLL is found and loaded fine. However, when I load the COM DLL in a different executable, the second DLL is not found. Both executables are in the same directory and have the same permissions. The COM DLL is a driver that provides a high-level interface for the executable; both executables are, theoretically, making the same calls.

Any pointers to things to investigate that could possibly cause this?

Comment: Are both the standalone EXE and the other EXE 32 bits or 64 bits, or are they different in that aspect?

Comment: Try loading the DLL with LoadLibrary so you can call GetLastError if it fails.  You might also want to use Dependency Walker on it.

Comment: @GTG both 32 bit running on 32 bit windows.

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't have access to the source for either executable, but can poke at the DLL using rundll32 at least.The only missing dependencies I see are IDSHIMS.DLL (fine) and MSVCR90.DLL (possibly an issue). MSVCR90.DLL is the best lead so far, but because this works in one exe and not another, I'm not sure what I should expect to see in Dependency Walker. I was thinking this would be more along the lines of differences in registered DLLs available to each exe? Thanks-

Comment: IDSHIMS.DLL always shows up as missing, but MSVCR90.DLL is definitely a problem.  My guess would be one exe was linked to the C runtime library statically, so it doesn't show a missing dependency, but the other uses the DLL version of the C runtime, so it does.  Get a copy of MSVCR90.DLL, copy it to \windows\system32, and that will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a not-so-exciting conclusion: unregistering the second DLL and reregistering it resolved the issue. I had registered the DLL multiple times without thinking that unregistering it first would do anything different.

Thanks @CareyGregory